# Populate an active record collection with different SQLs on the same model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to populate an active record collection from several SQLs on the same model. The only thing that differs between the SQLs is the where clause. My models have a type_id. As an example I have

```
models = Model.where("type_id = ?", 1)
logger.debug 'models.count ' + models.count.to_s  
m = Model.where("type_id = ?", 2)
models << m
logger.debug 'models.count ' + models.count.to_s
```

From that, my logfile shows me

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "models"  WHERE (type_id = 1)
models.count 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "models"  WHERE (type_id = 1)
models.count 1
```

The second SQL is not correct for my situation, I wanted

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "models"  WHERE (type_id = 2)
```

The only way I've found to get around this is to do `Model.all`, iterate over each and add the ones I want. This would be very time consuming for a large model. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure why your query is not working, that is strange. But wanted to give you a heads up on combining the two result arrays, `models` and `m`. You should use `+=` instead of `<<`. The shovel method will take the second array and put the whole thing into the last index of the first array, resulting in a nested array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you're looking for any `Model` with a `type_id` of either 1 or 2. In SQL, you would express this as an IN subclause:

```
SELECT * FROM models WHERE type_id IN (1, 2);
```

In Rails, you can pass an array of acceptable values to a `where` call to generate the SQL IN statement:

```
Model.where(:type_id => [1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @ArtOfCode what you want is to do the query on one pass. That being said, what you are trying to do there won't work because when you are adding with `<<` the object of your second query to the first one you are just appending the instance to the first collection. The object type of the resulting query is an `ActiveRecord_Relation` which happens to hold two instances of your custom models *(in this case `Model`)* but when you send / call `count` thats actually executing an `ActiveRecord` query.

How can you tell the difference? Well, if you do run that code you used and do:

```
models.count
```

You'll see that there's SQL executed for whatever the conditions of the query on `models` you did, however, if you do this:

```
models.length
```

You'll notice the result is `2`, and the reason is because the length of the collection of your own objects which happens to be inside the `ActiveRecord_Relation` is indeed two, and that is what happens if you use `<<`; it'll add object instances to the relation but that does not mean that they are part of the query.

You could even do this:

```
models << Model.new
```

And calling `models.length` would effectively return 3 because that is the amount of instances of your model that are contained within the relation, again, not a part of the query. So as you can see you can even add new object instances which have not even been saved to the database.

**TL;DR** if you want to query objects that are stored in the database do it on the query itself, or chain conditions at once, but don't try to mix activerecord relation collections.

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo Rubio. There's a lot of good information in your answer. I'll read up about chain conditions.